# Leer fecha en string y comparar

Tags: php

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto en php que no utilizo framework.
Quiero consultar un registro en una base de datos MSQL7 en el cual tengo un campo fecha guardado como `string` en el siguente formato `('d/m/Y')`. Lo que necesito hacer es muy sencillo, pero me cuesta manipular fechas con php. Quiero comprar esa fecha de la siguente manera: `si faltan 7 dias`, `si paso un año`, `si paso un año`, con respecto a la echa actual

Para saber si la fecha que recibo es anterior, posterior, o actual es lo siguente:

```
/* $vencimiento es un string que representa la fecha con formato d/m/Y */

if (strtotime($vencimiento) >= strtotime(date("d/m/Y"))) {
    // La fecha actual es inferior a la fecha de vencimiento
}

if (strtotime($vencimiento) < strtotime(date("d/m/Y"))) {
     // La fecha actual es superior a la fecha de vencimiento
}
```

Esto que hago me funciona actualmente, con fechas de vencimiento que son del año siguente.
Tambien creo que no esta mal lo que estoy haciendo

Comment: Si vas a hacer operaciones con fechas, deberías almacenarlas como tal; es muy fácil filtrar fechas en MySQL. De lo contrario te la pasarás haciendo conversiones cadena>fecha>cadena

Comment: El tema que yo ya tengo almacenado como mencione fechas en formato (d/m/Y) : 31/05/2022
Esta fecha la quiero comprar con `date('d/m/Y')` y tambien saber si falta una semana, o un mes, o si ya paso 1 semana o un mes, cosas por el estilo. Con js lo noto mas sencillo,

Comment: *"Rectificar es de sabios"*. Te vas a tardar más haciéndolo por la difícil que corrijiendo y hacerlo por la fácil.

Comment: deberia entonces, para una mejor practica, guardar las fechas en un formato como 2021-12-31 ?

Comment: Absolutamente: tipo DATE, DATETIME o TIMESTAMP.

Comment: Sigue esas recomendaciones para almacenar todo lo que sea fechas  y te puede funcionar al comparar fecha vs fecha, para obtener la diferencia de días, meses,  con las funciones de Mysql, [DATEDIFF](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff), [PERIOD_DIFF](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_period-diff)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Las fechas siempre se deben almacenar en la base de datos en formato:
`YYYY-MM-DD`, o `YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss` a según como necesites. Cuando le vas a presentar la información al usuario haces las respectivas conversiones, pero internamente le facilita mucho al sistema trabajar en el formato recomendado.

Guardada la información de esa manera, se pueden hacer operaciones de forma natural. Ejemplos:

*table1*

```
id      value
(INT)   (VARCHAR 45)
------+-----------
1       2021-01-28
2       2021-01-30
3       2021-02-16
4       2021-02-25
5       2021-03-03
```

A pesar que el campo es `VARCHAR` se puede hacer operaciones de comparaciones de fecha sin hacer conversiones de tipo.

```
> SELECT value FROM table1 WHERE value BETWEEN '2021-02-01' AND '2021-03-01'
value
----------
2021-02-16
2021-02-25
> 
> SELECT value FROM table1 WHERE value > '2021-02';
value
----------
2021-02-16
2021-02-25
2021-03-03
```

El mismo comportamiento sucede en PHP, y otros lenguajes, ya que el interprete puede hacer comparaciones entre caracteres:

```
> var_dump('a' > 'b');
bool(false);
> var_dump('b' > 'a');
bool(true);
>
> // Aplicando el concepto con fechas
> $var1 = '2021-02-25';
> $var2 = '2021-03-06';
>
> $t = '2021-02-15'; // Una cadena de prueba
>
> var_dump(($var1 < $t) and ($t < $var2)); // ¿está $t entre var1 and var2?
bool(false) // Correcto
>
> $t = '2021-02-28'; // Probamos con otro valor
> var_dump(($var1 < $t) and ($t < $var2)); 
bool(true) // Correcto
>
> $t = '2021-04-02'; // Una fecha mayor que $var2
> var_dump($t > $var2);
bool(true) // Correcto
>
> // La misma operación anterior usando otro formato de fecha
> $var2 = '25/02/2021';
> $t = '02/04/2021';
> var_dump($t > $var2);
bool(false) // X <-- Incorrecto
>
```

Obviamente lo anterior si funcionará si se hiciera antes la conversión tipo date(). Sin embargo con una lógica adecuada tu programa será más eficiente y compatible entre otros sistemas.

Comment: Muchas gracias.