# No funciona busqueda en rango de fechas con PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo el siguiente codigo php que lo llamo al hacer click en un boton de busqueda donde se seleccionan dos fechas:

```php
    <?php
include_once ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/includes/claseConexion.php');


if (isset($_POST['accion']) && $_POST['accion']=='listar'){


try
{
 
    $conexion = Conexion::singleton_conexion();
    

    $stm=$conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM presupuesto left join vehiculos on presupuesto.id_vehiculo=vehiculos.id_vehiculo left join clientes on presupuesto.id_cliente=clientes.idcliente WHERE (presupuesto.Fecha >='".$_POST['fechai']."' AND presupuesto.Fecha<= '".$_POST['fechaf']."') ORDER BY presupuesto.id_presupuesto DESC;");
      $stm->execute();

   $array=$stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo json_encode($array);
 
          
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    die($e->getMessage());
}
}
?>
```

El caso es que no me devuelve ningun registro. Tengo varios presupuesto cargados, pero si ejecuto la consulta en el motor de base de datos funciona perfecto.
Ya probe hacer var_dump de fechai y fechaf y la fecha llega en el mismo formato(dd-mm-yy) que tengo almacenado en la base de datos. De hecho la almaceno como un string:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y no se donde puede estar el problema, verifique el json resultante y no llega nada.

Comment: *Ya probe hacer var_dump de fechai y fechaf y la fecha llega en el mismo **formato(dd-mm-yy)** que tengo almacenado en la base de datos. De hecho la **almaceno como un string**.* Ese es el problema. Si almacenaste las fechas como string ahora no puedes hacer comparaciones que verifiquen si el valor de esas columnas es *mayor o igual que* o *menor o igual que* ni usar BETWEEN. Para que funcione tendrás con convertir esas cadenas a fecha, tomando en cuenta el formato. Lo más recomendable es que declares esas columnas como fecha, así evitarás este problema y posibles errores en los datos.

Comment: Bueno lo voy a intentar.. Aunque en el motor de base de datos lo paso entre comillas como string

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Leer fecha en string y comparar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/449860/80870)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

prueba utilizando `BETWEEN`, quedaría así:

`$stm=$conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM presupuesto left join vehiculos on presupuesto.id_vehiculo=vehiculos.id_vehiculo left join clientes on presupuesto.id_cliente=clientes.idcliente WHERE (presupuesto.Fecha  BETWEEN '".$_POST['fechai']."' AND presupuesto.Fecha<= '".$_POST['fechaf']."') ORDER BY presupuesto.id_presupuesto DESC;");`

Answer (score 0):

Funciono usando between aunque tuve que formatear la fecha, el codigo PHP quedo de la siguiente manera:

```php
<?php
include_once ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/includes/claseConexion.php');


if (isset($_POST['accion']) && $_POST['accion']=='listar'){


try
{
 
    $conexion = Conexion::singleton_conexion();
    

    $fechainicio = date("y-m-d", strtotime($_POST['fechai']));
    $fechafin = date("y-m-d", strtotime($_POST['fechaf']));
    $stm=$conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM presupuesto left join vehiculos on presupuesto.id_vehiculo=vehiculos.id_vehiculo left join clientes on presupuesto.id_cliente=clientes.idcliente WHERE (presupuesto.Fecha  BETWEEN '".$fechainicio."' AND presupuesto.Fecha<= '".$fechafin."') ORDER BY presupuesto.id_presupuesto DESC;");
        
  
      $stm->execute();

   $array=$stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo json_encode($array);
 
          
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    die($e->getMessage());
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Te recomiendo almacenar la fecha como DATE y al hacer el WHERE `DATE(presupuesto.Fecha) BETWEEN '".$fechainicio."' AND '".$fechafin."'`         te dará resultados más preciosos al usar fechas

Comment: Bueno lo voy a intentar..